# Ubuntu boots to purple/black screen using rEFInd and live USB stick

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, macbook-pro

I followed the instructions http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/ to add dual boot capabilities to my MacBook Pro (Mavericks 10.9.4)

I used the the 64bit (not AMD) version of Ubuntu 14.04. 
I used rEFInd 
I made the partitions in GParted (using Try Ubuntu from the live USB stick) and then used the install link from the desktop, choosing something else and installing it on the ext4 partition.

When I tried to do my first boot after install the screen went purple/black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by uninstalling rEFInd from Mac OSX (leaving the Ubuntu install untouched) and reinstalling it using these commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.8.3  
./install.sh --alldrivers
```

Apparently the --alldrivers option installs the file system drivers for rEFInd, and this enables the boot manager to access the Ubuntu kernel files on the Linux file system. (As a side note I got duplicates in the refind boot menu when I updated my Ubuntu as I then had more than one kernel on my system).

The Linux icon (penguin) that took me to the frozen purple/black screen remains and still behaves as such, but now at least I am able to choose another icon from the loader to access my newly installed Ubuntu.